# Force dash in Bibliography for author names also for first entry on page

Tags: biblatex

In `biblatex`, subsequent mentions of the same name list at the beginning of an entry are replaced
by a dash. The only exception is the first entry of a new page. How can I get rid of this? I want a permanent dash also for the first entry of a new page.

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{filecontents} 
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    
  @book{Pall.SC,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC}
}
    
     @book{Pall.SC2,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial2,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC}
}

 @book{Pall.SC3,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial3,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC}
}

 @book{Pall.SC4,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial4,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC}
}

 @book{Pall.SC5,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial5,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC}
}

 @book{Pall.SC6,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial6,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC}
}

 @book{Pall.SC7,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial7,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC7}
}

 @book{Pall.SC8,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial7,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC8}
}

 @book{Pall.SC8,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial8,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC9}
}


 @book{Pall.SC9,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial9,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC9}
}

 @book{Pall.SC10,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial10,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC10}
}

 @book{Pall.SC11,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial11,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC11}
}

 @book{Pall.SC12,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial12,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC12}
}

 @book{Pall.SC13,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial13,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC13}
}

 @book{Pall.SC14,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial14,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC14}
}

 @book{Pall.SC15,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial15,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC15}
}

 @book{Pall.SC16,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial16,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC16}
}

 @book{Pall.SC17,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial17,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC17}
}

 @book{Pall.SC18,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial18,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC18}
}

 @book{Pall.SC19,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial19,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC19}
}

 @book{Pall.SC20,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial20,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC20}
}

 @book{Pall.SC21,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial21,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC21}
}

 @book{Pall.SC22,
title = {Palladios. Dialogue sur la vie de Jean Chrysostome. 1: Introduction, texte critique, traduction et notes; 2: Histoire du texte, index et appendices},
editor = {Malingrey, Anne-Marie and Leclercq, Philippe},
series = {SC},
number = {341–342},
volumes = {2},
location = {Paris},
keywords = {Vita},
date = {1988},
}
@classictext{Pallad.Dial22,
author = {{Pall. v. Chrys.}},
xref = {Pall.SC22}
}
    
    \end{filecontents}
    
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
    \usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    

    
    \begin{document}
    \null\vfill
    genannt \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial}.
     \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial2}
      \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial3}
       \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial4}
        \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial5}
         \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial6}
          \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial7}
           \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial8}
            \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial9}
             \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial10}
              \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial11}
               \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial12}
                \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial13}
                 \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial14}
                  \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial15}
                   \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial16}
                    \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial17}
                     \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial18}
                      \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial19}
                       \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial20}
                        \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial21}
                         \autocite[Vgl.:][1, 1–5 (SC 341, 100–102 Malingrey/Leclercq)]{Pallad.Dial22}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\boolfalse{pagetracker}` before the bibliography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` explicitly checks if an entry is the first on a (double)page and suppresses the dash there to avoid the reader having to go back to the previous (double)page to check the relevant name. If you want the dash, you can remove the test for `\ifsamepage` from the `bbx:dashcheck` bibmacro:

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    (
       not bool {bbx@inset}
       or
       test {\iffieldequalstr{entrysetcount}{1}}
    )
    and togl {blx@dashed}
  }
    {#1}
    {#2}}
\makeatother
```